# Add emphasis github flavored markdown within code block

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to bold a portion of text within a code block in a github readme?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183610/how-to-combine-bold-and-code-sample-in-markdown) on StackExchange Meta works on Github too:

Use a `<pre>` tag (or `<pre><code>`) instead of ```` ``` ````, and use `<b>` tags around the part you want bold.

Comment: Note: You cannot use `<pre lang="...">` AND `<b>`. The syntax highlighting will take precedence!

Comment: I can confirm this solution works at least in StackOverflow. The source code was detected automatically and colores properly, combining correctly with the bold section.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the Markdown Preview Plus browser plug-in, though. I hate Markdown—it's so nonstandard (like HTML in the 1990s) and I keep having to resort to HTML to make basic stuff like this work.

Comment: @MichaelScheper I agree. Someone needs to publish a new comprehensive standard and keep it up to date. Perhaps it could start out as a collection of all the different standards and extensions out there, and gradually move from descriptive to prescriptive. Maybe you!

Comment: @linesarefuzzy: I'm so glad somebody else recognises this! Clearly, you are one smart developer, and would follow my standard if I developed it.  But are you the influential type, too? Can you help me convince the world to follow it, and help prevent this? https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Haha, well, according to SO my influence is 672. So, perhaps a better solution would be to support one of the projects that already had this brilliant idea, like http://commonmark.org/.

Comment: Okay, wacky idea: LaTeX? Already a super stable standard with a lot of functionality for many purposes, including code display. A .tex -> html renderer with syntax highlighting ought to be manageable.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot style your code snippet with bold/emphasis/italics.

You can always make comments explaining parts of the code, if that's what you want to achieve by emphasizing bits of your code.

Comment: Comments there is a good remark. Thank you a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

`sample`**`sample`**`sample`

Output:

`sample`**`sample`**`sample`